# Jenkins Git Publisher: How to commit code back to master after build?

Tags: android, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, git-push

I'm having some difficulty with Jenkins Git Publisher committing and pushing code back to master after my build. My build process increases a version number in one of my files and then I want to commit this file back into the repo, but I can't seem to get it to work.

In Source Code Management->Git, these are my settings:

- Repository Name: Android
- Branch Specifier: master
- Checkout/merge to local branch: master

Then, in Git Publisher, these are my settings:

- Push Only If Build Succeeds: checked
- Merge Results: checked
- Branch to push: master
- Target remote name: Android
- Notes: Note to push: Updating version
- Notes: Target remote name: Android
- Notes: Note's namespace: master

This is the output from Jenkins:

```
Pushing HEAD to branch master at repo Android
Adding note to namespace "master":
Updating version
```

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think jenkins git publisher plugin is not doing anything like

```
git add .
git commit -m 'xxx'
```

Plugin only perform push and optionally add note using [git-notes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html).

See notes here:

https://github.com/hamsterready/jenkins-git-publisher-test/tree/refs/notes/master

To achieve something like this: https://github.com/hamsterready/jenkins-git-publisher-test/commit/d80a1eef2133bee6d7a57b1b229ccd5990d2d606

I have added post-build step (execute shell script) with:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Updating git.properties'
```

And then enabled git publisher post-build action which pushed local commit to origin.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue for pushing back the changes to origin using Git plugin on Jenkins. What is the Git client plugin version you are using? 
There must be a bug in git client plugin and thus the behavior.

They fixed the issue related to push sometime back. Ref: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17242 .
And seems like its broken, as there is another bug filed for the same recently again:  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19442

If you read the discussion in the urls, the quick fix suggested is to downgrade Git client plugin to 1.0.5 and git plugin to 1.3.0. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using also Gradle for your builds, there is a [Git plugin](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) for it.

Here is the complete `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories { mavenCentral() }
  dependencies { classpath "org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.6.3" }
}
import org.ajoberstar.gradle.git.tasks.*

task tag(type: GitTag) {
    tagName = version
    message = "Release of $version"
}

task pushWithTags(type: GitPush){
    credentials{
        username = "karim"
        password = gitPassword
    }
    setPushTags(true)
}
task add(type: GitAdd){
    include("yourVersionFile.txt") 
    // or add everything with include("*") 
}
task commit(type: GitCommit){
    setMessage(commitMsg)
}
task pushNewVersion(){
    tasks.add.execute()
    tasks.commit.execute()
    tasks.tag.execute()
    tasks.pushWithTags.execute()
}
```

This is how you add, tag, commit, and push using the script (there is a [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) for doing that from within Jenkins):

```
gradle pushNewVersion "-PcommitMsg=hi" "-Pversion=0.1.1" "-PgitPassword=secret"
```